# Checking differentiability at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Check
$$f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^3y^3}{x^2+y^2} & x^2+y^2 \neq 0 \\
0 & x = y = 0
\end{cases}$$

is differentiable at $(0,0)$  or not
.

I have a very vague understanding of differentiability in case of multi-variable calculus . I know that if a function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at a point $(a,b)$ , then it can be uniquely represented in the form
$$f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)=Ah +Bk+h\phi(h,k)+k\psi(h,k)$$ where A and B are dependent on the point and the function that we are choosing , while $\phi(h,k)$  , $\psi(h,k)$ tend to $0$ as $(h,k)$ approaches $0$. This doesn't seem to fit here.

Hints please.

Comment: existence of partial derivatives is a sufficient condition for differentiability , not a necessary one.

Comment: Your function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ with derivative being the zero map, since the remainder is $r^2\sin^3\theta\cos^3\theta$.

Comment: @user2345678 partial derivatives exist . can i apply this definition that i stated in some way ?

Comment: Hint: The directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of the unit vector $u=(u_1,u_2)$ is $l'(0)$ where $$l(t)=f(u_1t,u_2t)$$

Comment: @MatthewPilling i am afraid i don't understand .

Comment: To check that $f$ is not differentiable, you should check if it is not continuous or do not have all directional derivatives in $(0,0)$. 

To ensure it is differentiable, you can check if the partial derivatives exists and are all continuous in $(0,0)$.

That's the usual procedure in these kind of problems.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3391522/check-differentiability-of-2-variable-function?noredirect=1

This proves directly it is differentiable, with $A = B =0.$

Or you can check that $\partial f/ \partial x (0,0) = \partial f/ \partial y (0,0) = 0$ and show that $\partial f/ \partial x$ and $\partial f/ \partial y$ are continuous on $(0,0)$, as in other points they are (because they are quotient of polynomials)

Comment: Thanks @user2345678 that helped .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative at $(0,0)$ exists if there is a linear operator $Df(0,0) = L$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)}\frac{|f(h,k) - f(0,0) - L \cdot (h,k)|}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}}= 0$$

Note that

$$\frac{|f(h,k) - f(0,0)|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} = \frac{|h|^3|k|^3}{(h^2+k^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{2^{3/2}}\underbrace{\left(\frac{2|h||k|}{h^2 + k^2} \right)^{3/2}}_{\leqslant 1}|h|^{3/2}|k|^{3/2} \\\leqslant |h|^{3/2}|k|^{3/2} \underset{(h,k) \to (0,0)}\longrightarrow 0$$

Hence the derivative at $(0,0)$ exists and is the zero operator,

$$Df(0,0): (h,k) \mapsto 0$$

You could have obtained a clue that this was a suitable candidate for the derivative by noting that the partial derivatives are both $0$, but this alone is not sufficient for existence.  A sufficient condition is that the partial derivatives exist in a neighborhood of a point and are continuous at the point.

Answer (score 1):

If $(D_uf)(0,0)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ in the direction of the unit vector $u=(u_1,u_2)$ you can compute $(D_uf)(0,0)$ directly as the following limit: $$(D_uf)(0,0)=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(u_1t,u_2t)-f(0,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}u_1^3u_2^3t^3=0$$ Note that $(D_uf)(0,0)=\vec{0}\cdot u$ is a linear function of $u$, so $f'(0,0)$ exists. If the above limit were *not* a linear function of $u,$ then $f$ wouldn't be differentiable at the origin. Check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678774/prove-function-is-not-differentiable-even-though-all-directional-derivatives-exi). As pointed out in the comments, a standard way to prove that a function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ is to show that $f_x$ and $f_y$ exist and are continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help Matthew